# remove and print prime numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, primes

I have an assignment due for class and the objective is to take an Array and run it through a method that will print the array out in reverse order, then run it through a second method to test if the number is prime then print the still reversed order array out without the prime numbers. I can get the reverse the order part fine, I am running into trouble with the prime numbers part:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // CTORs
        int[] MyArray = { 10, 8, 7, 14, 22, 11 };
        int[] myArray2 = new int[7];
        // METHOD CALLING
        MyArray = reverseOrder(6, MyArray);
        MyArray = primeCheck(MyArray, 6);
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++)
            System.out.println(myArray2[i] + " ");

    }// MAIN


    /*--------------------ARRAY PRIME TEST---------------------*/
    private static int[] primeCheck(int[] myArray, int num) {
        //prime
        boolean prime = true;
        int[] myArray2 = new int[10];
        //test all components of an array
        for (int i = num + 1 ; i >= 0; i++) {
            if (num % i > 0) {
                prime = false;
                System.arraycopy(myArray, 0, myArray2, 0, 4);
                return myArray2;
            }

        }
        return myArray2;
    }// ISPRIME REMOVE
}// CLOSE CLASS
```

my output is as follows:

```
11 22 14 7 8 10 0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0
```

I feel really rusty because this is the first assignment back after a long break, so any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `for (int i = num + 1 ; i >= 0; i++)` does not look right. Have you tried to debug your code step by step to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: in your prime check you don't check any of the elements of the array. you compare the total number of elements (6) with a counter variable.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray2` is defined and never filled with values. So every element is 0.

I think

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++)
```

must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely something wrong about `for (int i = num + 1 ; i >= 0; i++)`. Below is one way to achieve the objective.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] arr = { 10, 8, 7, 14, 22, 11 };

     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(!isPrime(arr[i])) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}

public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if(num < 2) return false;
    if(num == 2) return true;

    int remainder, divisor;
    divisor = num - 1;

    do {

        try {
            remainder = num % divisor;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            return false;
        }

        if(remainder == 0) return false;

        divisor--;

    } while (divisor > 1);

    return true;
}
```